# rails rspec capybara select not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

In my rails app, I have a select on the navigation bar as follows:

```
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">

  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
    <div class="navbar-default sidebar hidden-sm hidden-xs" role="navigation">
      <div class="sidebar-nav">
        <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
          <li>
            <h4 class="sidebar-title">SGPLAN</h4>
          </li>
          <li class="logo">
            <form action="#">
              <select name="" id="change_plan" class="form-control plan">
                <option value="1" id="plan_id" selected="">first </option>
                <option value="2" id="plan_id">other </option>
              </select>
            </form>
          </li>
```

and javascript in application.js to load the home page when the user selects a different option.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //...
    $('#change_plan').on('change', function(){
        var str = ''
        str += $( this ).val() + " ";
        setCookie("plan", str,1);
        window.location.href = "/";
    })
});
```

I have written the following test for this feature using rspec, capybara and capybara-webkit:

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature "Change plan", :js do
  background do
    login_as create(:admin_user), scope: :user
    Agency.current = Agency.find_by(initials: 'SECTI').id
    FactoryGirl.create(:other_plan)
    Plan.current = Plan.find_by(name: 'first').id
  end

  scenario "User changes the current plan" do
    visit "/milestones"
    save_and_open_page
    select('other', from: 'change_plan')
    # within '#change_plan' do
    #   find("option[value='2']").click
    # end
    # find('#change_plan').find('option', text: 'other').select_option
    expect(current_path).to eq("/")
  end
end
```

save_and_open_page results in the html snippet as shown above.

The result of running the test is as follows:

```
Failures:

  1) Change plan User changes the current plan
     Failure/Error: expect(current_path).to eq("/")

       expected: "/"
            got: "/milestones"

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/features/plans/change_plan_spec.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1 minute 1.71 seconds (files took 2.04 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure
```

If I use `find('#change_plan')...` or `find("option...")` (as per the commented out lines) in the test instead of the select, the result is the same.

My versions are follows (from `Gemfile.lock`):

```
capybara (2.7.1)
capybara-webkit (1.11.1)
database_cleaner (1.5.3)
factory_girl_rails (4.7.0)
rails (4.2.5)
rspec-core (3.5.4)
rspec-expectations (3.5.0)
rspec-mocks (3.5.0)
rspec-rails (3.5.2)
```

and `ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]`

What do I need to do get this test to work? Should I be using a different test platform? We are relatively committed to rspec but less so to capybara.

**Update**

I finally got this working with the help of Thomas and employing multiple suggestions that he provided.

1. There was a javascript error with the capybara webkit driver.
2. I tried the selenium driver but got a 503 error at the visit /milestones step.
3. I then switched to the poltergeist driver and found that the wait behaviour was also an issue - so I had to use have_current_path.

Comment: try adding a `sleep 1` before the `expect(...` call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using the `eq` matcher with current_path since it has no waiting/retrying behavior.  This means you're checking the path before the page has time to change.  Instead use the have_current_path matcher provided by Capybara

```
expect(page).to have_current_path('/')
```

Comment: have_current_path doesn't work either. It just gives a failure with a slightly different wording. I also tried sleep 100 and even combined have_current_path and sleep without success. So the lack of wait behaviour may be part of the problem - but there is something else that needs to be fixed as well. Any further suggestions?

Comment: If have_current_path didn't make a difference then it's not a waiting issue - the page isn't actually changing.  2 possibilities for that - 1. capybara-webkit isn't triggering a change when a new select is chosen (that would be a bug in capybara-webkit), although that is a behavior that is tested for in their tests.  You can try `find('#change_plan').trigger('change')` after the select to see if it works then.   2. You have an error in one of your JS assets thats stopping the change handler from ever being added.  Concatenation of assets can make errors show up in test that don't affect dev.

Comment: find('#change_plan').trigger('change') didn't work either. So that leaves the possibility of an error in a JS asset due to concatenation. But I committed the sin of pushing the change to production without having the test working. As I understand it, assets are also concatenated in production and, therefore, I would expect the feature to fail there as well as in test. But it is working in production. Any ideas on what more I might do to get to the bottom of this?

Comment: @mark.sack capybara-webkit doesn't support ES6 so it could be you're using some methods/syntax that capybara-webkit doesn't support (Array.prototype.find is a common one IIRC).  Have you tried looking at `page.driver.error_messages` to see if any JS errors are raised?